# Are usernames not unique (aka: how many Iains)?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, account

https://serverfault.com/users/9517/iain

https://serverfault.com/users/71060/iain

Am I missing something?  I certainly took a **sharp** intake of breath at a question posed by the newer Iain, then panicked that the old one had decided to leave SF and had his account deleted.

Comment: I wasn't the first http://serverfault.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all&search=iain

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usernames are indeed not unique on Stack Exchange.

Login tokens (OpenID) are uniquely associated with an account, and accounts are unique (identified by the account number), but you can have multiple accounts with the same display name.

Comment: Well, I live and learn.

Comment: *changes name to voretaq7*

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't have said it better than [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/25428/189912):

> People have the same names in real life. Isn't StackOverflow real life?

Comment: Is this the real life? Is this just fantasy?

Comment: Caught in a landslide

Comment: No escape from the onslaught of questions that could've been answered with 60 seconds googling... sorry, wrong song?

Comment: Doesn't really matter to me....

Comment: any way the users blow (up).

Comment: Because I'm easy come, easy go